# Output file showing adresses instead of values when using GTK+

Tags: c, gtk

I've been working on this project, and since I am a GTK newbie, I wrote the c code and compiled it and it seemed to run smoothly. However, when I added the GTK part, all I got in the output file was the same adress followed by the time:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct wa9t
{
     int h ;
     int m ;
     int s ;
}wa9t ;

typedef  struct client  {
    int numc;
    wa9t hd;
    struct client * suiv ;
}client;

typedef struct file{    
  struct client * premier  ;
  struct client * dernier  ;
  int nb_elt ;
}file;

file init  (file * f )
{
    f->premier = NULL ;
    f->dernier = NULL ;
    f->nb_elt = 0 ;  
}


int filevide (file *f)
{
    int x ;
    if (f->nb_elt == 0)
    {
        x=1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        x=0 ;
    }
    return(x);
}

int nb ( file * f)
{
    int x;
    x = 0 ;
    while (f->dernier != NULL)
    {
        f->dernier = f->dernier->suiv ;
        x = f->nb_elt;
    }
    return(x);
}

void emfiler  (file * f   , FILE * P_FICHIER )
{
    client * cour ;
    int a,b,i ;
    cour = malloc(sizeof(client));
    cour->numc = nb(&f)+1  ;
    cour->hd.h =heure() ;
    cour->hd.m = minu() ;
    cour->hd.s =sec() ;
    cour->suiv = NULL ;

    if (filevide(&f)==1)
    {
        f->premier = cour ;
        f->dernier = cour ;
        f->nb_elt = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cour->suiv = f->dernier ;
        f->dernier= cour;   
    }
    f->nb_elt++ ;
    P_FICHIER = fopen("fichier.dat", "a");
    fprintf(P_FICHIER, "%d "  ,f->dernier->numc);
    fprintf (P_FICHIER,"%d:"  ,f->dernier->hd.h);
    fprintf (P_FICHIER,"%d:"  ,f->dernier->hd.m);
    fprintf (P_FICHIER,"%d;\n",f->dernier->hd.s);

    fclose(P_FICHIER);
    system("sort /+1 fichier.dat /o fichiertrier.dat");
}


char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
{
    memmove(s + pos, s + pos + n, strlen(s) - pos - n + 1);
    return (s);
}

int heure()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
   char h[2];
   int hh;
   time ( &rawtime );
   timeinfo = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
   strdel(timeinfo,0,10);
   strdel(timeinfo,8,5);
   strncpy ( h, timeinfo, 3 );
   hh = atoi(h);
   strdel(timeinfo,0,4);
   return(hh);
}


int minu()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
   char m[2];
   int mm;
   time ( &rawtime );
   timeinfo = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));

   strdel(timeinfo,0,10);
   strdel(timeinfo,8,5);
   strdel(timeinfo,0,4);
   strncpy ( m, timeinfo, 3 );
   mm = atoi(m);
  return(mm);

}

int sec()
{

   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
   char s[2];
   int ss;
   time ( &rawtime );
   timeinfo = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));

   strdel(timeinfo,0,10);
   strdel(timeinfo,8,5);
   strdel(timeinfo,0,4);
   strdel(timeinfo,0,3);

   ss = atoi(timeinfo);
   return(ss);
}

void MessageEmfiler (file * f , FILE * P_FICHIER)
{
  if (((heure() > 18)||(heure() < 8)))
  {
     GtkWidget *dialog, *label, *content_area;
     GtkDialogFlags flags;
     GtkWindow *window;
     window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
     gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Gestion des tickets");
     g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
     gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 50);

     // Create the widgets
     flags = GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT;
     dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("Message",window,flags,("_OK"),GTK_RESPONSE_NONE,NULL);
     content_area = gtk_dialog_get_content_area (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
     label = gtk_label_new ("Desole, mais sakarna saye");

     // Ensure that the dialog box is destroyed when the user responds
     g_signal_connect_swapped (dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy),dialog);

     // Add the label, and show everything we’ve added
     printf("\a");
     gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (content_area), label);
     gtk_widget_show_all (dialog);
  }
  else
  {
      emfiler  (&f,&P_FICHIER );
      printf("\a");
  }

}

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
    file *f ;
    FILE * P_FICHIER;
    init  (&f) ;
    GtkWindow *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *button;
    system("color a");
    system("title GTK");
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Gestion des tickets");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 50);
    printf("%d",nb(&f));
    printf("\n");
    grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Obtenir votre ticket ");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (MessageEmfiler), (&f,&P_FICHIER));
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Quitter");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIbg0.png)

Comment: Could you fix the indentation and remove unnecessary parts from code?

Comment: You got this down for your lowercase "i"-s.

Comment: you missed me with this one, what do you mean exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting it here because it does not fit a comment.

First of all a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be much more useful... especially for you, because I'm pretty sure you'd find the problem by yourself.

Then you must **not** ignore compiler warnings, above all when you find some unexpected behavior. You have 31 warning! Here is the result of a quick compilation:

```
a.c: In function ‘emfiler’:
a.c:63:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 cour = malloc(sizeof(client));
        ^~~~~~
a.c:63:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
a.c:63:8: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘malloc’
a.c:64:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘nb’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 cour->numc = nb(&f)+1  ;
                 ^
a.c:47:5: note: expected ‘file * {aka struct file *}’ but argument is of type ‘file ** {aka struct file **}’
 int nb ( file * f)
     ^~
a.c:65:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘heure’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 cour->hd.h =heure() ;
             ^~~~~
a.c:66:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘minu’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 cour->hd.m = minu() ;
              ^~~~
a.c:67:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sec’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 cour->hd.s =sec() ;
             ^~~
a.c:69:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘filevide’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 if (filevide(&f)==1)
              ^
a.c:33:5: note: expected ‘file * {aka struct file *}’ but argument is of type ‘file ** {aka struct file **}’
 int filevide (file *f)
     ^~~~~~~~
a.c:89:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘system’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 system("sort /+1 fichier.dat /o fichiertrier.dat");
 ^~~~~~
a.c: In function ‘heure’:
a.c:106:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   timeinfo = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
            ^
a.c:107:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,10);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:108:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,8,5);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:109:16: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strncpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strncpy ( h, timeinfo, 3 );
                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from a.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,
              ^~~~~~~
a.c:110:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atoi’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   hh = atoi(h);
        ^~~~
a.c:111:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,4);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c: In function ‘minu’:
a.c:123:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   timeinfo = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
            ^
a.c:125:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,10);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:126:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,8,5);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:127:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,4);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:128:16: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strncpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strncpy ( m, timeinfo, 3 );
                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from a.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,
              ^~~~~~~
a.c: In function ‘sec’:
a.c:141:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   timeinfo = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
            ^
a.c:143:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,10);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:144:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,8,5);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:145:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,4);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c:146:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strdel’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   strdel(timeinfo,0,3);
          ^~~~~~~~
a.c:93:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tm *’
 char * strdel(char * s, int pos, int n)
        ^~~~~~
a.c: In function ‘MessageEmfiler’:
a.c:159:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
         ^
a.c:178:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘emfiler’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   emfiler  (&f,&P_FICHIER );
             ^
a.c:59:6: note: expected ‘file * {aka struct file *}’ but argument is of type ‘file ** {aka struct file **}’
 void emfiler  (file * f   , FILE * P_FICHIER )
      ^~~~~~~
a.c:178:16: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘emfiler’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   emfiler  (&f,&P_FICHIER );
                ^
a.c:59:6: note: expected ‘FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}’ but argument is of type ‘FILE ** {aka struct _IO_FILE **}’
 void emfiler  (file * f   , FILE * P_FICHIER )
      ^~~~~~~
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:188:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘init’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     init  (&f) ;
            ^
a.c:24:6: note: expected ‘file * {aka struct file *}’ but argument is of type ‘file ** {aka struct file **}’
 file init  (file * f )
      ^~~~
a.c:195:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
            ^
a.c:199:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘nb’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     printf("%d",nb(&f));
                    ^
a.c:47:5: note: expected ‘file * {aka struct file *}’ but argument is of type ‘file ** {aka struct file **}’
 int nb ( file * f)
     ^~
a.c:209:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_widget_show_all’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     gtk_widget_show_all (window);
                          ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:27:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:31,
                 from a.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:632:12: note: expected ‘GtkWidget * {aka struct _GtkWidget *}’ but argument is of type ‘GtkWindow * {aka struct _GtkWindow *}’
 void       gtk_widget_show_all            (GtkWidget           *widget);
```

Comment: i'm still a novice developper so i can't really debug a code using these

Comment: Well, you have a line number, an error description and access to internet: that's all you need, together with some will to learn.

Comment: ok , i fixed the implicit declaration error, gonna keep looking for the rest . thnx for helping

Comment: @Chihab Hajji, make sure you build with `-Wall` in your compiler options, and fix the problems as they appear.

Answer (score 0):

in function emfiler, you're sending the address of a pointer:

```
cour->numc = nb(&f)+1  ;
```

you can try

```
cour->numc = nb(f)+1;
```

edit:

let me point out a few more things that may help.

- to use malloc, include stdlib.h
- you send &f for a file pointer f at a few places. If you're trying to dereference pointer f, then you should use *f, or if you want to send the file pointer to functions, use f directly, not &f
- your init function assumes the pointer was allocated a memory. I believe you actually would want to malloc it at the beginning of init function, as that seems to be the intention in the call to init(&f) in main. And of course, you would want to update the pointer value of the caller, so you should pass pointer to pointer (if you just pass pointer, that pointer is copied at function call and the caller pointer doesn't change). So the function should look like:

  ```
  void init(file **f)
  {
    *f = malloc(sizeof(struct file));
    *f->premier = NULL;
    *f->dernier = NULL:
    *f->nb_elt = 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: How about in main, changing the line:  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (MessageEmfiler), (&f,&P_FICHIER)); to  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (MessageEmfiler), (f,P_FICHIER)); ?

Comment: still getting the same output

Comment: well , its not showing adresses instead i just get 1 followed by the time